# NodeJS ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: nodejs, express, pm2

Tengo un proyecto en Nodejs con express que subido en un VPS. El proyecto funciona localmente, pero tengo problemas cuando inicio con PM2.

En el proyecto estoy usando ECMASCRIPT 6 con import y export.

Busque en diferentes lugares y no encuentre una solución Agradecería tu ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que tiene que hacer es agregar el indicador: módulos experimentales (por lo que he leido) que admiten la nueva declaración de importación / exportación de es6, también el orden es importante.

El index pon el tuyo yo he puesto el de por defecto.

`"start": "node --experimental-modules src/index.mjs "`

Answer (score 0):

tenia ese error y lo solucione bajando a la version anterior del fetch, con estas dos lineas

```
npm i node-fetch@2.6.5
npm i @types/node-fetch
```

y con esas dos lineas solucione el problema